# Part of speech for qualifying adjective which takes NP outside normal domain of noun it modifies

Tags: adjectives

Is there a specific grammatical term for a qualifying adjective which takes the noun phrase fully outside the usual domain of the noun which it qualifies? For example:

- fake money;
- skew field (math.);
- simulated crash?

Comment: It's certainly not a different part of speech: syntactically there is nothing special about these. I'm not aware of a particular term that captures their semantics - indeed, I'm not certain that the distinction you are making is necessarily a sharp one.

Comment: **All** adjectives are partitive. That is their function: The **black dog**; the **hot** topic. "Fake" is no different, grammatically, from "**hot** money" or "**foreign** money.

Comment: How is this any different from _transferred epithet_?

Comment: From the duplicate: they're **anti-intersective** [Adj] +[N] (or [Natt] + [N]) pairs. An example is 'a fake Picasso': a fake Picasso is not a Picasso (though a forged painting _is_ still a painting). The jury is out with 'toy gun' as _gun_'s definition has now been broadened to include the toy replicas.

Comment: With examples like 'alleged criminal' where the referent may or may not be a criminal, the term **non-intersective** applies.

Comment: I've acknowledged in the UI that this is a dupe and that the answer is non-intersective. Sorry for not finding this before asking.

Comment: (If anyone wonders why anyone would care, I'm trying to solve a question about the grammar of another language, and need to know what terminology to search for).

Comment: You need to say more clearly what this phenomenon is that you are trying to identify.  If you are a surrealist, any adjective may qualify any noun.  There is a place for 'squelchy clouds', 'wobbly trees and 'high pitched silence'.  Even without surrealism, it is often possible to find a context in which an unusual pairing makes sense.  You might call a rock pool a 'liquid hotel for crustaceans'.  Can you provide some whole sentences as examples of what you are looking for?